# "Method expression is not of Function type"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have the following JavaScript Code:

```
const { Command } = require('commander');
const program = new Command();

const createPassword = require('./createPassword')

program.version('1.0.0').description('Commandline Password Generator');

program
    .option('-l, --length <number>', "Length of your Password", '8')
    .option('-nn, --no-numbers', "Remove Numbers")
    .option('-ns, --no-symbols', "Remove Symbols")
    .option('-s, --save', "Save Password to passwords.txt")
    .parse();

const { length, save, numbers, symbols } = program.opts();

// Get generated Password
const generatedPassword = createPassword(length, numbers, symbols);
```

The "createPassword" File looks like this:

```
const alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const numbers = '1234567890'
const symbols = '!@#$%^&*_-+='

let createPassword = (length = 9, hasNumbers = true, hasSymbols = true) => {
    let chars = alpha;

    hasNumbers ? (chars += numbers) : '';
    hasSymbols ? (chars += symbols) : '';
    return chars;
}

module.exports = createPassword();
```

The output is the following:

```
const generatedPassword = createPassword(length, numbers, symbols);
                          ^

TypeError: createPassword is not a function
```

I know, that this question was asked about 6 or 7 Years ago and I tried everything but it just does not work.
Node is installed in the current version and so is jQuery.

What on earth am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You didn't export your function from createPassword.js

Comment: you are right. i actually did it with "module.export = createPassword" but with brackets like this "module.export = createPassword()"
Man, thank you so much!

Comment: IMO when ask question and refer to an old question, I suggest you link to the old question and give you question a fresh question title, do not quote it with double quote.

Comment: Well ok thank you for that tip!